# Making "Rounds" in a Rock-Paper-Scissors Game?

Tags: javascript

I know this is a very popular/simple game to make, but I'm having a bit of trouble. I have made a rock-paper-scissors game in javascript and I've managed to make it work so that it will prompt the player to choose rock, paper, or scissors, get the computer to randomly pick an option, and a means for it to say "you lose" or "you win". The problem is that I'm required to make 5 rounds. That's the issue I'm having. I, for some reason, cannot seem to get the code to prompt the user 5 times. It only prompts the user once and runs the same code each time. My code is as follows:

```
     function playRound(playerSelection) {
    let computerSelection = getComputerSelection();
    if (playerSelection == "rock") {
        addToList(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        if (computerSelection == "rock") {
            result = "It's a tie";
        }
        else if (computerSelection == "paper") {
            result = "You lost! Paper beats Rock";
            computerScore++;
        }
        else {
            result = "You won! Rock beats Scissors";
            playerScore++;
        }
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "paper") {
        addToList(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        if (computerSelection == "rock") {
            result = "You won! Paper beats Rock";
            playerScore++;
        }
        else if (computerSelection == "paper") {
            result = "It's a tie";
        }
        else {
            result = "You lost! Scissors beats Paper";
            computerScore++;
        }
    }
    else {
        addToList(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        if (computerSelection == "rock") {
            result = "You lost! Rock beats Scissors";
            computerScore++;
        }
        else if (computerSelection == "paper") {
            result = "You won! Scissors beats Rock";
            playerScore++;
        }
        else
        result = "It's a tie";
    }
    h1.textContent = result;
    player.textContent = playerScore;
    computer.textContent = computerScore;
    game();
}

function game() {
    if (playerScore === 5) {
        end.style.display = "block";
        message.textContent = "You Won!";
    }
    else if (computerScore === 5) {
        end.style.display = "block";
        message.textContent = "You Lost!";
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help or direction that is given. I have tried putting my "playRound" function outside of the loop, but it gives me the same issue. What would make it prompt twice?

Thank you!

Comment: The `window.prompt()` code is not in a function, so it will only be called once. You have to make it part of the functions that can get called multiple times.

Comment: Ah! Okay, this makes sense, let me see if I can add that in the for loop then....

Comment: I moved the variables "playerSelection" and "computerSelection" to the loop. So it's now right above "playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)". This seemed to do the trick as it now prompts me 5 times! Now, how would I test if this is actually going all 5 rounds and and counting each time? Would I just console.log each round? I want it to print each round if the user is winning or losing.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to say “solved” - just accept an answer (as you already have done :) )

Comment: And please stop deleting significant portions of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are asking for player's prompt only once i.e. it is outside the playRound method.
Try moving the following snippet into playround method.

```
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

const playerSelection = window.prompt("Enter your choice: ").toLowerCase();

Comment: Got it! So, just add the "continue" at the end of the loop? Forgive me, I'm still new to loops, thus my questions my be a little redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you an incorrect answer earlier. I've updated my answer to reflect what I think is the real problem (i.e. you are asking the user for a choice exactly once, hence the issue).Move the calls to window.prompt as well as computerPlay method into the playRound method.

Comment: No worries at all! Thank you. I moved the variables "playerSelection" and "computerSelection" to the loop. So it's now right above "playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)". This seemed to do the trick as it now prompts me 5 times! Now, how would I test if this is actually going all 5 rounds and and counting each time? Would I just console.log each round? I want it to print each round if the user is winning or losing.

Comment: Never mind! That totally did the trick! Thank you so much! I have gotten it to work exactly how I want it. I unfortunately do not have enough points to upvote you, but I will mark you correct! Thank you SO much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in JS, so please correct me if i'm wrong, but what seems to be the case is that this variable:

```
const playerSelection = window.prompt("Enter your choice: ").toLowerCase();
```

is only initialized a single time with that function's return. (because it is outside any function) Accessing the variable only recalls it's value it was initialized with, causing the main loop to run over and over again with only that initial value.

replacing that line with someing like:

```
function getPlayerSelection(){
    return window.prompt("Enter your choice:").toLowerCase()
}
```

and replacing everywhere you use `playerSelection` with `getPlayerSelection()` should fix this issue.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It was my mistake as I forgot to say this was solved. But, yes, my issue was that the playerSelection was not placed in any function, which was causing all the issues. Thank you very much for the help :)